# Tried using pd.read_csv() function but a UnicodeDecodeError shows up

Tags: python, jupyter

So my database is this file called 'mnist.csv'
The code I used to read the file is:

```
data = pd.read_csv('mnist.csv', engine = 'python')
```

Upon executing the code, the following error shows up:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 10: invalid start byte
```

I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)

Over there I used the code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('mnist.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

But it again shows an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8954-8955: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Your data isn't UTF-8. Where did you get it?

Comment: Looks like the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/76773620/407651

Comment: Yes that was my earlier post but I wanted to post another question with more clarity so that it would be more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can check the format used in the dataset by trying several values in the `encoding` parameter, here the `latin-1` seems to work better than `utf8`. Then check the separator used (comma, semi-colon, tab...) :

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('mnist.csv', encoding='latin-1', sep=',')
```

Since the data you want to get is the classical MNIST, we can get it directly from `keras` like so :

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the same error shows up:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 10: invalid start byte

Comment: Hello Aarush K ! Hope you are well. Maybe you can try with `latin-1` encoding argument. Does it works ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to execute that :P

Comment: @AarushK `encoding="latin1"`...

Comment: Yes exactly, `data = pd.read_csv('mnist.csv', encoding='latin-1')`

Comment: Im sorry to bother yall again but it shows an error again T_T
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 15, saw 2

Comment: Do you know if the separator is an another thing that a comma ? It is a semi-colon ?

Comment: I updated my answer :) ! Can you try it and tell me if it is better :)

Comment: To complete previous comment, add argument sep=';' in pd.read_csv(), an see how it wordks. The separator could also be something else in some cases ('\t', '-', etc...) but coma and semicolon are the most frequent.   


Also, keep in mind that both parameters `encoding` and `sep` have to be correct to allow file to be read, so you may need to try several combination before finding the proper one : 'utf-8' / '";", or "latin-1" / ";", etc... Read the pd.read_csv() documentation to learn more: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thanks @S_Crespo ! Yes, you can try `data = pd.read_csv('mnist.csv', encoding='latin-1', sep=';')`

Comment: The errors are never ending! Now it shows this:
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 75, saw 3

Comment: Could you post a link to the csv file? (the link where you downloaded it from)

Comment: Yeah sure give me a minute

Comment: I got it from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/oddrationale/mnist-in-csv

Comment: This dataset is a classic one :) ! You can have it directly in keras. I updated my answer :)

Comment: I opened it with no specific argument. But there may be some tricks: what is you OS (Linux, Windows, Mac) ? Bc defaut encoding is not the same (utf-8, windows, etc). Also, did you first unzip the content of zip file before reading it? And lastly, the zip file contains 2 files mnist_train and mnist_test but none just named mnist, so are you opening the proper file?

Comment: @tlentali Yeah its pretty common, its my first time doing a project on Python and I'm actually trying to do an Image Classification Project!

Comment: @S_Crespo its Windows

Comment: @tlentali Thanks for the update! I actually dont use the module keras since my instructor told me to use the Pandas package

Comment: @S_Crespo Hi! I tried unzipping the file like you said and it ended up becoming 2 files!
One is named mnist_train and the other mnist_test

Comment: So you must do: mnist_train = pd.read_csv(path/to/mnist_train.csv) and same for mnist_test. First try with the default parameters and if it doesn't work try changing one parameter (sep and encoding) at a time

Comment: Side note: since you are on Windows, if there are backslashes in you file path (see example further), please add the letter 'r' before the string that represents the path to your file: this ensures that the backslash character '\' is considered as part of the string and not as an escape character. Forgetting the "r" (that means "raw straing") may cause an "encoding error" as well. For instance, if your file is in C:\Users\Aarush\Documents\mnist_train.csv, then you must type: `pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Aarrush\Documents\mnist_train.csv")`

Comment: So glad to read that @Aarush K and very happy to help :) ! Can you accept the answer please ?

Comment: Oh sure, sorry I'm new to this website

Comment: I changed the answer several time to answer the problem as OP tried several propositions we provided with @S_Crespo that I just upvoted. I will bring more in the answer to cover all our propositions.

Comment: I updated the answer to cover the pandas part and the keras plan b solution. Always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I sum up my above comments here in hope that it helps next users.

The problem is that your filepath is a string that contains the backslash character (`\`) **since you are on Windows**.

(Note : this wasn't visible in your sample code, but my guess is that you simplified the path, since this solution worked).

And this character is also used to encode special characters. For instance, "\n" corresponds to line break.

So if your path is, say, `"C:\Users\Aarush\Documents\mnist_train.csv"`, Python is trying to figure out what character the `\U` stands for. This can have many unexpected effects.

To avoid this and open your file properly, ensure that you add a "r" before the path, like this:

`mnist = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Aarush\Documents\mnist_train.csv")`

This "r" stands for "raw" and means you turned your string into a raw string where all characters must be interpreted literally (and not as escape characters).

- if you still have the error, this comes from the CSV file parsing: in that case, also check the separator (comma, semicolon... : this is the parameter "sep" in `pd.read_csv()`) and the file encoding (parameter "encoding" in `pd.read_csv`, usually  "utf-8")

Comment: There are no Windows paths in the question. How can that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks mzjn for your comment. Since the proposed maneuver worked, my guess is that the path was simplified by the author of question.